# different syntax for accessing method of literals

Tags: python

Why we can directly access a method belonging to a string literal:

```
keyfunc="STR".__eq__
```

or a float constant:

```
keyfunc=1.0.__eq__
```

or even:

```
keyfunc=1..__eq__  # 1. is the same float as 1.0
```

but the same code for an integer throws a syntax error?

```
keyfunc=1.__eq__ # WRONG!
```

The last line should be written as:

```
keyfunc=(1).__eq__
```

Why and when are the parens required?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Reason for this to happen:

It's because `1.` gets treated as a float:

```
>>> 1.
1.0
>>>
```

And obviously:

```
>>> 1.0__eq__
SyntaxError: invalid decimal literal
>>>
```

Would give an error.

It's because Python operates from left to right. So the dot would belong to `1` to make it a float.

### Workaround for this other than parenthesis:

So the way to fix it would be to add a space between `1` and the dot `.`, like:

```
>>> 1 .__eq__
<method-wrapper '__eq__' of int object at 0x00007FFDF14B2730>
>>>
```

#### Reasoning for these workarounds to work:

The reason this works is because:

```
>>> 1 .
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
>>>
```

Gives an error, so it doesn't get treated as an integer.

It's the same case for `(1)`.

As you can see:

```
>>> (1).
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
>>>
```

### Documentation references:

As shown on [this](https://docs.python.org/3.5/reference/lexical_analysis.html#integer-literals) page of the documentation:

> ```
> integer        ::=  decimalinteger | octinteger | hexinteger | bininteger
> decimalinteger ::=  nonzerodigit digit* | "0"+
> nonzerodigit   ::=  "1"..."9"
> digit          ::=  "0"..."9"
> octinteger     ::=  "0" ("o" | "O") octdigit+
> hexinteger     ::=  "0" ("x" | "X") hexdigit+
> bininteger     ::=  "0" ("b" | "B") bindigit+
> octdigit       ::=  "0"..."7"
> hexdigit       ::=  digit | "a"..."f" | "A"..."F"
> bindigit       ::=  "0" | "1"
> ```

The above is the integer literal definitions in Python.

Comment: I suspected it is somehow related to the decimal point, but on the other hand there is no real ambiguity in `1.__eq__`, because it has only one valid meaning and I expected some kind of lookahead could solve it... Apparently it makes a bigger problem for the parser as I thougt. Thank you for answering in detail.

Answer (score -1):

It also has to do with the python compiler specification. But the main confusion is that we don't know who the period belongs to, i.e.
`keyfunc=[1.]__eq__` or `keyfunc=1[.__eq__]`. Without specifying the `(1)` or (as mentioned) adding the space, we don't know whether it's the end of an expression or not.